# Iterate over a CSV file and skip while lap?

Tags: php, arrays, csv, if-statement, boolean-logic

I want to iterate over a CSV file and check if on position row[1] are certain countries. If yes, the while lap should be skipped to the next row.

But at the moment it is failing due to my if condition:

```
$countries = array("Österreich", "Schweiz", "Niederlande", "Großbritannien", "United States");

while (($row = fgetcsv($inputFile, 0, $delimiter)) !== false) {
        foreach ($countries as $country){
            if(((stripos($row[1], $country === false))) && stripos($row[0], "Card")){
                echo $row[0] . "\t => \t" . $row[1] . "\n";
            }
        }
... some other code (Dealing with the values) ...     
}
```

To continue coding I was checking if my statement is right and if I get the desired values. But I do not.

I want only to get the values where the country is not one of the countries in the array and if the title in `row[1]` contains the word `card`. But if I use this if condition I get no values.
But what is wrong?

This is a CSV sample:

```
products_name;products_edition
"PlayStation Network Card 20€";"Deutschland ";
"PlayStation Network Card 50€";Österreich;
"Playstation Plus Live Card - 365 Tage";Deutschland;
"PlayStation Network Card 10£ ";Großbritannien;
"PlayStation Network Card 20$";"United States";
```

So actual I should get `"PlayStation Network Card 20€";"Deutschland ";` and `"Playstation Plus Live Card - 365 Tage";Deutschland;`. But I do not...

Does anybody know why and if yes how can I fix that?

And my second question is:
If one value of `products_edition` is matching with one country from my array, the actual while lap should get skipped because I do not want to handle the product if it is from those countries. But how can I tell that that actual while lap?

I do not want to stop the hole while loop, only the while lap where `row[1]` is matching one of the countries in my country array.

Does anybody has an idea?
Greetings and Thank You!

**EDIT:**
I know now how to skip the actual loop lap and to tell the loop to continue with the next lap. I just use `continue;`. But there is still my other if condition problem... :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$countries = array("Österreich", "Schweiz", "Niederlande", "Großbritannien", "United States");
while (($row = fgetcsv($inputFile, 0, $delimiter)) !== false) {
    if (in_array($row[1], $countries) && strpos($row['1'], "Card") !== false) {
        continue;
    }
    echo $row[0] . "\t => \t" . $row[1] . "\n";
//... some other code (Dealing with the values) ...     
}
```